# interacting with python's input() from C#'s process

Tags: c#, python

This is my **python script**:

```
print("hello world")
theInput = input(">\n")
print("eingegeben: " + theInput + "\n")
```

I want to call this script from C#'s and feed it with input. But only "hello world" gets printed.

content of the calling function in **C#**:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "I:\\testskript.py";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
proc.Start();

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("asdf");

string content = "";
while (true)
{
    if (proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
         break;         
    content +=proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() + "<br />";
}

webBrowser1.DocumentText = content; // the output goes to a webBrowers on the GUI

proc.Close();

return;
```

Comment: Try `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("asdf\n");`

Comment: doesn't help...

Comment: I'm not sure, but there could be buffering or something on the `StandardInput` `StreamWriter`, either on the C# side or on Python's side.  Try calling `proc.StandardInput.Close()` once you're done writing to stdin.

Comment: didn't help on the C# sharp side. How would I do it on the python side? I added a sys.stdout.flush(), but that didn't help either.